# Adding a chatango to bootstrap issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So im making an "anime" site (which is just me trying to learn elementary code) I need to add a chatango box aligned to the right of my screen (I tried this using an iframe tag which did somewhat work but it popped up the box in the wrong place at the footer with an error saying "directory could not be found") Im not really sure what to do can someone give me an example and tell me where to stick it? 
{"handle":"absolutionanime","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"CC0000","b":100,"c":"FFFFFF","d":"FFFFFF","k":"CC0000","l":"CC0000","m":"CC0000","n":"FFFFFF","p":"10","q":"CC0000","r":100,"pos":"br","cv":1,"cvbg":"CC0000","cvw":200,"cvh":30,"ticker":1,"fwtickm":1}}

Comment: Can you include more code?

Comment: Have you tried floating the div to the right?

Comment: How would I do that? (im a complete neophite still learning terminologies.)

Comment: Give the "float: right;" style to your parent object, in your case, give the chatango container style="float: right;"

Answer (score 0):

The `float: right;` is like the following:

```
    <div style="float: right;"><script id="cid0020000161037121510" data-cfasync="false" async src="http://st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 300px;height: 500px;">{"handle":"absolutionanime","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"ffffff","b":100,"e":"ffffff","h":"ffffff","l":"cccccc","m":"dadada","q":"ffffff","r":100,"sbc":"bbbbbb","fwtickm":1}}</script></div>
```

or, define the margin:

```
    <div style="margin-left: 1050px;"><script id="cid0020000161037121510" data-cfasync="false" async src="http://st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 300px;height: 500px;">{"handle":"absolutionanime","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"CC0000","b":100,"c":"FFFFFF","d":"FFFFFF","k":"CC0000","l":"CC0000","m":"CC0000","n":"FFFFFF","p":"10","q":"CC0000","r":100,"pos":"br","cv":1,"cvbg":"CC0000","cvw":200,"cvh":30,"ticker":1,"fwtickm":1}}</script></div>
```

Let me explain a little. We use `<div>` to define a section or division. We use `margin-left` to create a margin from left. For example, you want yours to be on the bottom, you can use `margin-top` to make it at the bottom. If you just like to create a margin at the whole part, use `margin`. Comment if you are still having a hard time.